# Navigation drawer´s list header´s typeface

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an app with navigation drawer. It has a list with header. The header has an image and one text. I want to set Typeface to this text but I don´know how.

My code is like this:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        View header= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
```

My header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen_resul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/leon_trans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="by xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I pass the header typeface? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the xml?

Comment: I have updated my question with the xml

Comment: Where you want to set a typeface? in your TextView1?

Comment: You want an specific Typeface or just want to put bold in your text?

Comment: see my answer hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inflating header to list:

```
textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
"fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to do this :

You can replace your `TextView` for this

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="by xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="yourtypeface"
 />
```

Also you can do it with code..

You have to create a folder named "fonts" and then inside of it just copy your fonts and then you can do :

```
    TextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/THEFONTYOUWANT")
TextView.setTypeface(tf);
```

And if you only want to decore your TextView you can do by this way :

```
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Calling TextView.setTypeface(tf) will not work, that's calling a static setTypeface method which doesn't exist. You're probably doing this because your TextView variable has no name, but it's not correct. While I'm here, you could mention that using android:typeface will only work with values predefined in the framework, not any typeface.